# Make a slideshow image scale on content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently working on a project for internship and got a problem with the website. Let me describe the problem so I have a slideshow on the page and got a button and a div placed on it with `position: absolute;`. But the image doesn't scale depending on the content so it goes out of the image.

This is my js, html and css code for the slideshow and button and clear div:

```
 **JS Code:**
    <Script>
        var i = 0;
        var images = [];
        var time = 3000;
    
        // Image list
        images [0] = 'img/image1.png';
        images [1] = 'img/image2.png';
        images [2] = 'img/image3.png';
        images [3] = 'img/image4.png';
    
        // Change Image
    function changeImg() {
    document.slide.src = images[i];
    
    if (i < images.length - 1) {
    i++;
    } else {
    i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout("changeImg()", time);
    }
    
    window.onload = changeImg;
    </Script>
    
    **Html code:**
    <div class="slideshow-content">
        <!-- Slideshow -->
        <img class="slideshow" name="slide">
    
        <!--White box on slideshow-->
        <div class="DivOnImage">
            <p class="TitleOnImage">UITZENDEN ZOALS HET HOORT</p>
            <p class="TextOnImage">'DE VRIJE WERKERS is een unieke, bewezen en door overheid goedgekeurde backoffice methode
                waarmee uitzendkrachten <b>nooit in vaste dienst</b> hoeven, <b>bruto uitbetaald worden</b> (en zo meer
                overhouden), <b>beter verzekerd</b> zijn, <b>pensioen</b> opbouwen, de <b>administratieve rompslomp wordt
                    geëlimineerd</b>, en <b>uitzendbureaus meer verdienen.*</b></p>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            <!--Button on slideshow-->
            <button class="button3" type="button">MEER INFO</button>
        </div>
    </div>

     **CSS code:**
    * {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Calibri;
    }
    
    IMG.slideshow {
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
        max-height: 340px;
        width: 100%;
    }
    
    .button3 {
        background-color: #5BD8C0;
        position: absolute;
        width: 157px;
        height: 35px;
        top: 250px;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: white;
        font-weight: lighter;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
    
    .button3:hover {
        background-color: #68BBCE;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    .DivOnImage {
        position: absolute;
        width: 70%;
        height: auto;
        top: 60px;
        background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        padding-left: 30px;
        padding-right: 30px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
    .TitleOnImage {
        font-size: 38px;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 30px;
    }
    
    .TextOnImage {
        color: black;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 15px;
        max-width: 100%
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i understood,  you need to change this:

```
IMG.slideshow {
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    max-height: 340px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

to this:

```
IMG.slideshow {
    object-fit: cover;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

If you want to strict the height and width to a certain limit the use again

`max-height` and `min-height`

Comment: That didn't do anything as the image is not in a div with the others so it just scales the image not based on the other divs.